# javascript site root

Tags: javascript, path, document-root

I have this site that I need to find the root folder / plus the actual folder its works out of.

My problem here is that during development i have the folder with in my local server that in turn is with in its own folder:

Then online I then have the development site within a folder, so it can all be tested before the live production etc.

LOCAL SERVER:
localhost/mytestSiteA/...

LIVE SERVER TEST FOLDER:
www.asite.com/devbuild/....

Now I can retrieve the root via the

```
    document.location.hostname
```

But i need then to add the folder name after this so that I can load in content etc when in developement mode.

LOCAL SERVER

```
 document.location.hostname + '/mytestSiteA/'
```

LIVE TEST SITE

```
 document.location.hostname + '/devbuild/'
```

But my issue is, is there an easy way to gain this inner folder rather than setting up variables determined on whether in local dev, live dev or live mode, as can be a pain, and would be nice to gain the current inner folder dynamically rather that manually changing etc so that I can add my paths correctly.

Also would help as if I have a folder within this that also loads in js script it can obtain its full path.

LOCAL SERVER:
localhost/mytestSiteA/subsection/...

LIVE SERVER TEST FOLDER:
www.asite.com/devbuild/subsection/...

I hope I have made this as easy to understand and put across.
Si

Answer (score 21, accepted):

try to [`switch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch)

```
switch (document.location.hostname)
{
        case 'asite.com':
                          var rootFolder = '/devbuild/'; break;
        case 'localhost' :
                          var rootFolder = '/mytestSiteA/'; break;
        default :  // set whatever you want
}
```

and then use

```
var root = document.location.hostname + rootFolder;
```

Answer (score 3):

This is what worked for me after the `switch` clause.

```
var root = location.protocol + '//' + location.host + rootFolder;
```

Answer (score 2):

if someone needs to move a step back

```
location.href.slice(0,location.href.lastIndexOf("/"))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can map the url localhost/devbuild to localhost/mytestSiteA and use the first url to test your site locally. In your javascript you can always assume the devbuild folder then. That way you don't have to change anything else.

Answer (score -4):

use relative paths so you don't need to get to the root folder

this doesn't work on sites with friendly urls with folders in the links

Comment: Could you please elaborate more your answer adding a little more description about the solution you provide?