# Get root path of application in javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net

`window.location.origin` works fine but my application is hosted in different directory, I mean, root url of production is `xyz.com/InnerDirectory`. On local host `window.location.origin` works but on production it gives `xyz.com` but I need `xyz.com/InnerDirectory` How can I achieve this?

Comment: How do you expect the browser to know the root of your application?

Comment: hmm. right. means there is no way using javascript? other ways?

Comment: I suggest you use a `switch` like here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12259958/javascript-site-root.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Javascript can't know what's the the root path of your application.
But since you tagged your question with `asp.net`, you can use virtual paths and asp.net will handle the paths for you.

So instead of:

```
<sometag src="xyz.com/InnerDirectory/something.css">
```

Write this:

```
<sometag src="~/something.css">
```

[Read more here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178116.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).

BTW, if you use ASP.NET MVC, it's even easier as you should use the `@Url.Content` \ `Url.Action` helpers